# automatically resize sharepoint promoted links

Tags: promoted-links, responsive

I would like to have the promoted links tiles automatically resize depending on browser size. Kind of a responsive way.
Is there any quick way to do this or change the sizes.

Would I have to make the website fully responsive to have this feature.

Also im looking for a plugin I can just use to make SharePoint site responsive.
I'm happy to purchase one

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

This website helped me figure out a way to do it.
http://www.balestra.be/2014/04/easy-way-display-promoted-links-tiles-multiple-rows.html

I just added a **script editor** web part on a page where the promoted links were and combined the code as follows. I modified the code so that the tiles will wrap automatically as the width is set to 100%.

```
<style>
/*display rows of items by width*/
.ms-promlink-body {
      width: 100%;
}
/*hide the arrows when you have more items than viewable*/
.ms-promlink-header{
display:none;
}

</style>
```