# Sharepoint Promoted Links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, promoted-links

How to  view all my promoted links on my page. I don't like how I have to use the arrow to go to all my apps. I want to be able to view all my 20 apps from promoted links on my page.

Answer (score 0):

In the promoted links app that you created: click on the "List" tab > "Create Column" drop down > select "All Promoted Links." This a complete view including "Title," "Background Image Location," "Description," "Link Location," "Launch Behavior," "Order." From there you can do a "Quick Edit" and/or edit each that are listed.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the promoted links is often the prefered option, and it is fairly easy.
Have a look at this question:

[automatically resize sharepoint promoted links](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123172/automatically-resize-sharepoint-promoted-links)

This will also ensure that the promoted links will be resposive